# ECDHE-* Cipher Suite Webpolygraph

Tags: openssl, centos7

Anyone knows whether Webpolygraph support ECDHE-* based Cipher suites?

I tried settings Ciphers array of SslWrap in to following

```
["ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256"],
```

SSL handshake fails with the below error

```
ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher
```

And the same set of Ciphers with exact SSL cert works in Apache on same server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with webpolygraph software. The application doesn't have support enabled for ECDHE-* based Cipher Suite with OpenSSL version

> 1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64

which is the latest openssl in CentOS 7